# installing otrs pages are downloaded instead of shown

Tags: linux, perl, otrs

I'm trying to install OTRS in Ubuntu 14 (parallels VM).
I've followed [this](http://www.geoffstratton.com/2013/08/install-otrs-help-desk-ubuntu-12-04/) tutorial along with the official tutorial in otrs github page. Every step as went well until step 10 - where I need to access the page on the browser.

I'm openning http://localhost/otrs/installer.pl
but Firefox tries to download the installer.pl instead of showing the instalation page like every tutorial and Youtube video guides say...

what might wrong? Can someone please help?

Comment: It appears that your apache install is not recognizing Options +ExecCGI, in OTRS's config. Do you have mod_cgi installed?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I installed all the dependencies that the tutorial indicated. Maybe I missed something? Can you point me out a bit on where to check that? (http://i.imgur.com/6Y4ZxcY.png?1)

Comment: A Google search for "ubuntu mod_cgi" results in the very first hit leading to an Ubuntu page which explains how to activate mod_cgi. Really, about half the questions here are actually asking "can you show me how to use Google".

Comment: I apologize, but I have a rather vague idea to what mod_cgi is. A google search reveals posts saying "cgi-bin not working" and rather unspecific things to someone as unexperienced as me on this matter. I will look through this thought, thanks.

Comment: **solved it!** [solution](http://askubuntu.com/questions/403067/cgi-bin-not-working). all I needed was to do "a2enmod cgi" and then "service apache2 restart". Thank you very much @sam-varshavchik

Comment: Yes, as I said, this was the first hit in Google. So, your missing information was that mod_cgi has to be enabled, and how to enable it.